# Count a sub-string inside a string

Tags: php

```
$string = "This is <a href="http://www.google">a</a> string with a link and I want to count the value of href attribute"
```

I have a string, and I want to output 10 characters from that string in html.

The problem is that I echo out 10 characters but I count also the chars inside the a tag. I could just simple ad the strlen of `"<a href=""></a>`" but I will never now the length of the value of href attr. How I find that value?

Edit:

On a blog there is an excerpt you see in a sidebar, not the hole post. I use a custom function to get the excerpt by counting the letters. I want like 100 character from the post. I want also to keep an eventual link. But the function counts also the character "< a href="..." > < / a >" and the final string is shorter. I just wanted to find out the length of that dynamically generated href value to add it to my excerpt length variable.

Is this clear enough or i'll get another minus?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. `http://www.google` is not 10 characters (and misses the tld btw), nor is `<a href=""></a>`. Please clarify the question. What are you trying to count/achieve?

Comment: Fyi, the string you posted contains a syntax error due to unescaped quotes. Put it in single quotes to avoid the error and the ugly escaping.

Comment: Questions is not clear. I think you want to count the letters instead of the tags?

Comment: I suppose he wants just the text (tags, etc excluded).

Answer (score 2):

Use the strip_tags() function to remove the html inside, then substring the cleaned string.

```
<?

$string = "i am <a href='http://www.google.com'>a</a> string with links";

$clean = strip_tags($string);

echo substr($clean,0,10);

?>
```

Comment: That was my guess, too. (I mean if we got what the question was supposed to mean)

Comment: I suppose question was not so well spelled, but i'm quite sure this solution it's what he needs because he said: "but I count also the chars inside the a tag". I don't think he actually wanted to get the length of href attribute, even because string may contain more than one <a> tag or other attributes, or other tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood what you're trying to do, but just an idea :

If you complete strip tags from your string and have something like "This is a string with a link...", would that work? If so, here's what you need...

```
$string = strip_tags($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Blogs contain anchors,images,tags and paragraph's.

If you want to grab an excerpt from the blog for the sidebar as you suggest, you target the first paragraph and remove its tags, the reason you remove the tags is because you then need to count the string and you dont want those in your way.

```
 if(!function_exists('excerpt')){

     function excerpt($string, $len='300'){

         // look for the first instance of a closing paragraph tag
         // +4 to add the closing tag back, then strip them.
         $new_string = strip_tags(substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "</p>")+4));

         // now shorten the string to the required length.
         $str = substr($new_string, 0, $len);

         // find the last space in the string
         // this will be used as the offset in the last substr
         // so we dont end up with words like ( paragr ) 
         $index = strrpos($str, ' ');

         // finally return the new string and append ( ... )
         return substr($str, 0, $index) . '&hellip;';

         //you might want to wrap it in a <p> tag when done
     }
 }
```

-

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(excerpt($string, 200));
```